# How to unit test Nest Interceptor

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm looking for some insight on unit testing an interceptor in `Nestjs`, please bare with my limited understanding of unit tests as I'm still fairly new to them, so feel free to explain concepts that seem rather trivial, as I would appreciate it nonetheless!

Just for the sake of this question, I'll borrow the code from the `Nestjs` documentation, specifically, the `LoggingInterceptor`, since that's the one I implemented in my project.

### Here is the logging interceptor from the official docs.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class LoggingInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    console.log('Before...');

    const now = Date.now();
    return next
      .handle()
      .pipe(
        tap(() => console.log(`After... ${Date.now() - now}ms`)),
      );
  }
}
```

I've tried and failed a few times at setting up a simple unit test that just shows the `console.log` was called twice, once before the `next` call is made, and once after.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily create a Unit Test for the logger interceptor in this way:

```
  it('should log to console', async done => {
    const mockHandler: CallHandler = {
      handle: () => throwError(new Error('try and retry')),
    };
    const mockExecutionContext = ({} as unknown) as ExecutionContext;
    const spy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');

    loggerInterceptor
      .intercept(mockExecutionContext, mockHandler)
      .subscribe(
        _ => _,
        () => {
          expect(spy).toBeCalled();
          done();
        },
      )
      .unsubscribe();
  });
```